# PHPMYADMIN throws alot Errors (LINUX Ubuntu) [Works!]

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just installed PHPMYADMIN on ubuntu and it says "Some errors were discovered on the server! Please look at the bottom of this window" before and when logged in . I counted them there are 43 Errors. One of them is :

```
Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Url.php#221
 http_build_query(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($numeric_prefix) of type string is deprecated

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Url.php#221: http_build_query(
array,
NULL,
string '&',
)
./libraries/classes/Header.php#231: PhpMyAdmin\Url::getCommonRaw()
./libraries/classes/Header.php#282: PhpMyAdmin\Header->getJsParams()
./libraries/classes/Header.php#214: PhpMyAdmin\Header->getJsParamsCode()
./libraries/classes/Header.php#142: PhpMyAdmin\Header->_addDefaultScripts()
./libraries/classes/Response.php#100: PhpMyAdmin\Header->__construct()
./libraries/classes/Response.php#134: PhpMyAdmin\Response->__construct()
./libraries/common.inc.php#432: PhpMyAdmin\Response::getInstance()
./navigation.php#16: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

I habe no idea why they are there and how to remove them do you have a idea how to fix them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completly deleting phpmyadmin it works!